# How to match carriage return with no linefeed in python

Tags: python, regex, carriage-return, linefeed

I am trying to use regular expressions in python to find carriage returns \r in a string which have no following linefeed \n, thus being a likely error.

However, my regex allways matches, and I do not know why:

```
>>> import re
>>> cr = re.compile("\r[^\n]", re.X)
>>> rr= rege.search("bla")
>>> rr
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000003793AC0>
```

How would the correct syntax look like?

Comment: read about "lookaheads".

Comment: Specifically, a negative lookahead.

Comment: You were right about the typo in the syntax. However corrected, as it is in my script, it still does not work. I rarely used lookaheads. Will do if it helps, but what is the explanation for my code not working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\r(?!\n)
```

In `Python`:

```
import re
rx = r'\r(?!\n)'
for match in re.finditer(rx, string):
    # do sth. here
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using verbose mode (`re.X`) and a non-raw string. That means your regex has a literal carriage return and line feed in it. As these are whitespace characters and you're in verbose mode, the carriage return outside a character class is completely ignored. Your regex is effectively `r'[^\n]'`, matching any non-line feed character.

Use a raw string. As others suggested, a negative lookahead would also be better for a "not followed by" assertion:

```
r'\r(?!\n)'
```